# Implementing Excel's NETWORKDAYS Logic using python to show business days (Weekdays)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, datetime

I am trying to implement the logic of excel networkdays formula in python using numpy.busday_count method. But i could not get expected output. Attached is the output from the excel and code
[image]

Below is the code.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
start_date = date(2020, 3, 30)
end_date = date(2020, 1,1)
np.busday_count(start_date, end_date)
```

o/p: -63
Expected output : -64

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numpy function is exclusive of the end_date argument whereas the excel function is inclusive of the end_date argument. Look at the row for May 5th. Excel says there are two days between 5/4 and 5/5 because excel is counting the 4th and the 5th. Numpy is only counting the 4th. This is why your answers are only ever off by 1. Try incrementing end_date by +1 in python to achieve the same results.

```
np.busday_count(start_date, end_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Since many of your end dates are before your start dates, though, that may not work for all cases. You may need to do something like this

```
max_date = max(start_date, end_date) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
min_date = min(start_date, end_date)
np.busyday_count(min_date, max_date) * np.sign(end_date - start_date)
```

Edit 1: Had order of numpy function arguments wrong. I have corrected it.

Comment: Could you share what the error was so I can better help? I do see a spelling error in your code. busday should be busyday.